# Correctly centering a fixed <div> element

Tags: css

I used this css to center a fixed `<div>` block. but it appears at the left bottom corner of `<body>`.
What's the problem?

```css
#console {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    
    margin: 0  auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="console">Example</div>
```

Comment: Because it is `fixed`. The centrally align trick using margin can only be applied to elements that are positioned relatively or statically.

Comment: So, if you fix it in your site, how will future visitors of this quesiton understand what the issue was?

Comment: I'll delete it. so many downvotes!

Comment: Don't get discouraged. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. IS the question neat and clear now? remove the on-hold flag!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's now the best ever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100px;
left: calc(50% - 50px); // 50px is half of 100px
```

Live example:

```css
#console {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px); // 50px is half of 100px
}
```

```html
<div id="console">Example</div>
```

Note that `calc` [requires modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). More on `calc`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation)

This way you say that the element should be 0px from the bottom and it should be in the middle of the screen (but you neeed to take into account that the element has some width, therefore minus 50px).

http://howtocenterincss.com/ - this is quite good to learn about centering in CSS (try to guess how you would do it before you see the result :-))

Comment: @FelixKling Is that calc() a js pre-declared function? or Can I remove it?

Comment: `calc()` is a CSS function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc (support is good: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you've set `position: fixed` on the element, which means that it is taken out of the normal document flow and `margin: 0 auto` doesn't work on it.

Instead you could set `left: 50%` and then a negative `margin-left` equal to half the width. Try this:

```
#console {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    /* your other rules... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100px // however wide you want it to be
```

you've done fixed positioning which removes the item from the normal page flow. By default they have a left of `0`.

because you used fixed positioning, `margin: 0 auto` does not work the same way as it does for elements in the normal document flow (such as static). You must use absolute positioning, relative to the items nearest absolute or relatively-positioned parent.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed position is in collision with your centering the element by margin. Try left:50%; instead of margin: 0 auto;